# jQuery: Select an Element by Knowing it's Left Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select an element by left position?

I want to do something like this:

```
$(".timeline_item").find("Where left position === 300");
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return all `.timeline_item` with left == 300

```
$(".timeline_item").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css("left") == 300;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I didn't know filter existed.  Cool stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You could check it with `.position()`:

```
$(".timeline_item").filter(function() {
  return $(this).position().left == 300;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
    $(".timeline_item").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css("left") == 300;
});
```